# Parse through a nested array and save it in mysql db with parent id

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, laravel-5.6

I have a nested array like the following:-

```
array(
    array(
        'id' => 45cfeteuid536hjj929,
        'name' = 'Cuisines',
        'children' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 45gcfeteuid536hjj929,
                'name' = 'Itlaian',  
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 45bjfe78ng5d536hjj92,
                'name' = 'Indian',
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'id' => 457hfe78ng5d53ghy56j,
                        'name' = 'Punjabi'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I have a table like this:-

```
|--------------------------------|
|   id  |   name   |  parent_id  |
|--------------------------------|
```

I want data to be inserted like this:-

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|   id  |   name     |  parent_id  |    api_id                  |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|    1  |   Cuisines |      0      |    45cfeteuid536hjj929     |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|    2  |   Italian  |      1      |    45gcfeteuid536hjj929    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|    3  |    Indian  |      1      |    45bjfe78ng5d536hjj92    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|    4  |   Punjabi  |      3      |    457hfe78ng5d53ghy56j    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
```

The parent_id of the child is the id of the object to which it belongs. The id of the table are autoincrement value generated automatically by the mysql db.

For example:-

- Step 1: While saving Cuisine, the id (autoincrement in nature) saved
  is 1. Since it is the root, hence parent_id = 0.
- Step 2: While saving    Italian, the id (autoincrement in nature)
  saved is 1. Since it is a    child of Cuisines, the parent_id = 1

How can I save the nested array in such way?

Comment: Please share your try ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand : the `parent_id` is the id `id` of an other rows in the same table?

Comment: @MickaelLeger, updated the doc

Comment: Ok so `parent_id` will be 0 for each `root parent` and the child should take the `id` of the parent as `parent_id`. I don't know if it's a good practice to do so (what happen if you delete a parent, you need to delete all child?), but one way to do it could be to use recursive function maybe where you store the last `insert id` and use to it after? Are you using PDO?

Comment: No. I am using Laravel Eloquent.

Comment: Ok, can't help you I don't know Laravel but one way to achieve it so : you can make a recursive function maybe something like `function insert_data($array, $parent_id = 0) { ... }`, now you need to insert the first "level" of the array and use `$parent_id` as `parent_id` in your table, then if you have a second level you use the function with `insert_data(/* your second level array*/, /* the last parent_id you just insert*/)` and so on untill you have no more level in your array

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to generate `insert` statements that look like this (assuming your table is called `tab`):

```sql
insert into tab(name, parent_id, app_id) 
    select 'Cuisines', coalesce(min(id), 0), '45cfeteuid536hjj929' from tab
    where app_id = '';
insert into tab(name, parent_id, app_id)
    select 'Itlaian', coalesce(min(id), 0), '45gcfeteuid536hjj929' from tab
    where app_id = '45cfeteuid536hjj929';
insert into tab(name, parent_id, app_id)
    select 'Indian', coalesce(min(id), 0), '45bjfe78ng5d536hjj92' from tab
    where app_id = '45cfeteuid536hjj929';
insert into tab(name, parent_id, app_id)
    select 'Punjabi', coalesce(min(id), 0), '457hfe78ng5d53ghy56j' from tab
    where app_id = '45bjfe78ng5d536hjj92';
```

These queries will find the parent ID via the `app_id` that parent should have. No value for the `id` column is inserted, as it is assumed that the database will generate it upon insertion.

Here is a recursive PHP function which generates those statements. You'll have to adapt it to actually execute those statements with whatever API you use (PDO, mysqli, ...):

```
function insertRecords($data, $parent = "") {
    foreach($data as $row) {
        // Replace next echo statement with the code to actually execute this SQL:
        echo "insert into tab(name, parent_id, app_id) select '$row[name]', coalesce(min(id), 0), '$row[id]' from tab where app_id = '$parent';\n";
        if (isset($row["children"])) insertRecords($row["children"], $row["id"]);
    }
}
```

Assuming your nested data structure is stored in variable `$data`, call the above function like this:

```
insertRecords($data);
```

Comment: Good answer but I think after one call the recursive function will forget the main nested array. I mean it will run for one complete level but not all, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: As long as there is a children property it will continue going deeper.

Comment: @ShashikumarMisal, why do think it will *forget*? Both `$data` and `$row` are local to the function's execution context. They are not forgotten.